# Unable to restore stock OS on Nexus S

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s, stock-android, restore

I had a post on https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14999/how-can-i-restore-the-default-os-on-phone-that-has-custom-build
however this got closed because it was a possible duplicate. Unfortunately the duplicate did not answer my question so I am posting again with further details.

Basically I had built the Android source and flashed this to my phone and now I would like to go back to the stock version.

The link in the duplicate points to the following recovery file http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_crespo/f182cf141e6a.signed-soju-ota-102588.f182cf14.zip

I renamed this to update.zip, and reboot into recovery. I then get a triangle with an exclamation mark. Then I hit the power and volume up key again and see more options, so I then selected 'apply update from /sdcard'.

I receive the error:

```
 E:failed to verify whole-file signature 
 E:signature verification failed 
 Installation aborted
```

How can I restore my phone with stock Gingerbread?

Comment: Explaining why your case is different is perfect :).  I didn't see your comment on the other question -- feel free to flag a question and fill in your reasoning if you think a question should be re-opened to make sure we see it.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure how to do this (I'm new to android.stackexchange so I may not have enough privileges yet to do this!)

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize you needed 15 rep for that. I'll have to remember to comment on new users' questions so they can `@Matt` in their comments.

Answer (score 2):

It's an official update, so the signature should be perfectly valid.  There are a couple things to check:

- You didn't mention where you saved the update.zip.  Make sure it's in the `/sdcard/` folder -- try viewing it via a file manager on your phone to ensure it's there.
- I assume you've done this already, but make sure your bootloader is unlocked.
- The download might have been corrupted.  Try the download again, and verify its validity with the MD5 sum (`3e8908941043951da5a34bb2043dd1a0`)
- What's your specific model number?  Perhaps this update doesn't work for your model.

  - You can try this 2.3.6 for the GT-i9023 / GT-i9020t: http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_crespo/1ada25375426.signed-soju-ota-189904.1ada2537.zip
  - Or this 2.3.6 for the GT-i9020a: http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_crespoa/0b9c8148de0d.signed-sojua-ota-189904.0b9c8148.zip

Comment: Thank-you, I have the GT-i9020T, I tried your first link, ie [GTi9020t](http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_crespo/1ada25375426.signed-soju-ota-189904.1ada2537.zip) however I still receive the same error :(

I believe my bootloader is unlocked, when I go into the bootloader it says: _Lock State - Unlocked_.

I do not have access to the File Manager to check that it is in `/sdcard/`, however when I plug in my phone to my PC, I dump the file in the first folder that appears, presumably this is the root of the `/sdcard/`.

Comment: @lost_bits1110 That might be the external SD card (`/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/`) rather than the internal SD storage (`/mnt/sdcard/`).  Samsung devices are weird like that.  Both drives should be mounted to your PC though, so try the other one?  I'm really surprised you don't have a Files app or anything (is that an AOSP thing?) but you should be able to side-load one, e.g. [AndExplorer](http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andexplorer/#download).

Comment: Yes it looks like its an AOSP thing, I wasn't able to find any kind of File Manager type app on here. Also I don't have the Marketplace nor can I connect to a network, so I won't be able to get [AndExplorer](http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andexplorer/#download) unfortunately :(

Comment: Okay - when I connect my phone to my PC and run my Android app, I can open up the DDMS view in Eclipse, and I see the File Explorer. In here I see a folder `/mnt/sdcard`, and my update zip file is here (though I do not see a `/mnt/sdcard/external_sd` folder)

Comment: @lost_bits1110 Hmm.  In that case you *could* try using the `fastboot update` command via the Android SDK.  It's supposed to ignore signatures if you want to risk it.

Comment: I appreciate all the help, unfortunately I receive the error: `error: failed to load 'update.zip'`. I then tried `fastboot devices` and it comes up empty, though `adb devices` works fine - sigh!! I will have to keep at it

Comment: You have to be in fastboot mode (not recovery) in order for fastboot utility to recognize the phone.

Comment: @Chahk - thank-you, but how do I get into fastboot mode? The only options I see are _Reboot bootloader, Reboot, Recovery, Power Off_

Comment: Try Bootloader mode. Also, fastboot expects the images to be on your computer, not on your phone's SD Card.

Comment: @Chahk - thank-you, yes when I press Power+Volume Up then I am in bootloader mode, and when I select _Reboot bootloader_ it quickly reboots into this same bootloader mode. I see _Fastboot mode_ and _Lock state - unlocked_ in red letters at the top. Unfortunately in this state, typing `fastboot devices` still returns nothing.